# Creating a program with Book class and TestBook class in Java

Tags: java, class, object

I'm trying to create java program that allows user to enter the book
number and the program will show the price of the book chosen. I've
created the book class and there's no syntax error in but most
probably there's logic error and the class TestBook has errors
in invoking the input. can you help me? im lost :( here's my code:

```
class Book{

    String title;
    String author;
    double price;
    int option;

    //constructor
    Book(String title, String author, double newPrice){
        title = title;
        author = author;
        price = newPrice;

    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }
    public String getAuthor(){
        return author;
    }
    public double getPrice(){
        return price;
    }
    public int getOption(){
        return option;
    }

    public void setPrice(int option, double price, double newPrice){
        if (option == 1){
            price = 20.00;
            newPrice = price;
        }
        else if (option == 2){
            price = 15.00;
            newPrice = price;
        }
        else if (option == 3){
            price = 23.90;
            newPrice = price;
        }
        else if (option == 4){
            price = 27.30;
            newPrice = price;
        }
        else if (option == 5){
            price = 50.00;
            newPrice = price;
        }
        else if (option == 6){
            price = 13.50;
            newPrice = price;
        }
    }
    public void setOption(int newOption){
        option = newOption;
    }
}
```

The TestBook class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestBook{
    public static void main (String[]args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        //The Book List
        System.out.println("The Book List");
        System.out.println("1)How to do programming 12th Edition by Liang.\n2)Malaysian Food Recipe by Nadia Bt Mahmud.\n3)What is Islam by Ustad Manzoor Malik.\n4)Urban Legend by Christine R.M.\n5)Fundamental of Calculus by Prof. Abu.\n6)How to raise your kids by Salsabila\n");
        System.out.println("Choose your book number to know the price: ");
        int option = input.nextInt();

        Book b1 = new Book(theOption(option);// invoke the option to get the price
        System.out.println("The price is: "+ b1.getPrice);


    }
    //Method option
    public static int theOption(int option){
        return option;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the specific issues/errors you receive?

Comment: You are calling constructor of Book with one argument,dont see that in the class shared

Comment: "the value of the local variable is not use" this is the error in my TestBook class

Comment: @NadhiraRizky Post further detail as edits to the Question rather than as Comments.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `()` in your method calls :

Replace

```
System.out.println("The price is: "+ b1.getPrice);
```

with

```
System.out.println("The price is: "+ b1.getPrice());
```

Beside that error, you are calling a constructor that doesn't exist :

```
Book b3 = new Book (8));
```

Your Book constructor accepts 3 parameters. And you have an extra `)` in that call.

Comment: Book b1 = new Book(theOption(option)); can i invoke the option like this?

Comment: @NadhiraRizky I'm not sure what "invoke the option" means. when you write `new Book(..)` you are creating a Book instance. You must have a Book constructor with parameters matching the parameters you pass in the `new Book(...)` call.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of problems with your code.

1. You ask for input on a book, but don't use a switch or if statement to use that input.  You will always print all three outputs, regardless of what the user inputs.
2. You have a constructor for the Book object with two parameters, but when you call the constructor with Book b1 = new Book(1)  you only use one.  This will give an error unless you have a constructor with only one parameter.
3. In your SetPrice function, you are shadowing your object's variables, which menas the local copy of Price will get the new value, not the object's copy of Price.

There are more but this will get you started.